# Listing recently modified pages

Tags: umbraco

How would I list URLs of recently modified pages on an Umbraco website?

Preferably with mod date and author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All documents have information like created/updated timestamps so in Razor you could do something like this...

Razor Example:

```
var root = Model.AncestorOrSelf();
var documents = root.Descendants().OrderBy("UpdateDate desc").Take(10);

<ul>
    @foreach (var doc in documents)
    {
        <li>@string.Format("{0} - Updated by {1} on {2}", doc.Name, doc.WriterName, doc.UpdateDate)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Note that I am not 100% sure that the WriterName property is updated with each publish so just check that.